# Not able to input numbers in autoCompleteTextView android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

In this AutoCompleteTextView i am able to enter all alphabets and special characters, just not numbers. Issue is observed on lollipop and above. works fine on kitkat

```
     <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/editTextSearchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/searchclear"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:dropDownHeight="160dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="Enter Location"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/theme_color"
            android:textColorHint="@color/theme_color"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
```

textWatcher used on the edit text box :

```
    autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if(editable.length() > 0)
                autoCompleteClearButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                autoCompleteClearButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you facing this issue across all devices are in specific devices. I have checked this in Genymotion emulator with OS version Lollipop and Marshmallow . Its working without any change in you xml.

Answer (score 1):

try using the android:inputType property in the layout file, set it to number or text

Answer (score 1):

add this line in your xml

```
  <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/editTextSearchView"
                ......
     android:inputType="number"
                .......
                ...... />
```